# C: How to use sizeof to split a char?

Tags: c, byte

I have a char array which I want to split for every 16 bytes. How is that done in C? The purpose is substitute every byte in the 16 bytes with something else.

I have already implemented the substitution function, so I just need to use it for every 16 bytes. 
In pseudo code:

```
      void sub(unsigned char* s){

                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                {
                    state[i] = S[state[i]]; //S[] is a char array (S-Box). which consists of the values state needs to be substituted with.
                }

    }
    int main(void){
        char message[] = "This is the message I want to encrypt!"
for every 16 bytes {    
sub(message);
}
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give some examples of what you mean, and the code you have tried?

Comment: `sizeof` tells you how many bytes something is, I can’t possibly see how this would help you.

Comment: Are you trying to perform block encryption/decryption?

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure: I need to do it as I trying to implement AES-128 encryption. So, let's say that a plain text is greater than 128 bits, then I need to split it for every 16 bytes, and substitute with S-Box.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "split"

Comment: I mean that I need to handle every 16 bytes. So, if the plaintext consists of 160 bits then here it will split by two

Comment: Are you trying to calculate how many blocks you'll need?  Something like: `numBlocks = (sizeof(array) / 16) + (sizeof(array) % 16 ? 1 : 0);`?

Comment: Have changed the OP with a pesudo code to explain what I mean

Answer (score 0):

An example would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sub(char *array, size_t size, char target_char)
{
    size_t num_segments = size / 16;
    for(size_t i=0; i<num_segments; ++i)
    {
        array[15 + i * 16] = target_char;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("need 3 args\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t size;
    char *array = argv[1];
    printf("original char array: %s\n", array);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%zu", &size);

    sub(argv[1], size, 'x');

    printf("new char array: %s\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is very vague, but this won't `substitute every byte in the 16 bytes with something else`.

Comment: Have changed the OP with a pesudo code to explain what I mean